# MqttConnectOptions members not recogized by Android Studio 3.1.1

Tags: android, mqtt

I am writing a straightforward mqtt client.   For some strange reason Android studio 3.1.1 can't resolve any member function of MqttConnectOptions.

None of the members functions of MqttConnectOptions are recognized by the compiler.

All the examples I can find on the web use the MqttConnectOptions members.  I'm baffled!

What simple thing am I missing?

```
package com.grayraven.garage;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttActionListener;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final String TAG = "Garage_Main";
    private static Context mContext = GarageApp.getAppContext();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContext = this.getApplicationContext();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    final String broker = "10.211.1.127:1883";
    final String password = "monkey123";
    final String subscriptionTopic = "garage_door";


    MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
    options.setUserName("pi"); //cannot resolve setUserName!!!
    options.setPassword(password.toCharArray()); //cannot resolve setPassword!!!!


    String clientId = MqttClient.generateClientId();
    MqttAndroidClient client = new MqttAndroidClient(mContext, broker,
                    clientId);

   /// rest of code works so omitted for clarity
```

**app build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.grayraven.garage"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation('org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
}
```

Comment: plz add your gradle file

Comment: gradle file added per @sontruongit request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a rookie mistake, I was trying to set the options outside the code section of the main activity.

Never mind.

Answer (score 1):

Your code to import MQTT dependencies for Android are not correct. Please try this one.

**Step 1:** Remove these lines from your *build.gradle* file

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/"
    }
}

implementation('org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
```

**Step 2**: Add these lines to *build.gradle* file of your **Android Studio project**. This is top-level build.gradle file not the one in app forder where you declare all dependencies of your project.

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-snapshots/"
    }
}
```

**Step 3**: Add these lines to *build.gradle* file of your **Android app**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.1.0'
    compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1'
}
```

Finally Clean, Sync then Build your project.